# How do I read a Board?

Tags: power-electronics, remote-control, board, remote

I have opened a remote and tried to read it.
Quite tricky if I'm honest.

I'm trying to replicate this DIY. On instructabels (Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-home-automation).

http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-home-automation/step8/Home-Automation/#step1

Very simply put, I want to connect my raspberry pi GPIO with this remote and turn my light on and off.
The Tutorial said each button should have 2 connections, I tried to follow each but have been unable to find anything?
How do I read this board?

[image: Board front]

Comment: Just probe the remote with an oscilloscope, then generate the timing with the pi

Comment: Don't have one, sorry

Answer (score 4):

In the second photo, each gold disk is divided into two separate contacts by the dark line zig-zagging across it.  Those two contacts are the contacts of that switch.  The switch button will have a conductive area that shorts those contacts when the button is pressed.

Comment: Ok thanks, so how would i connect this to my raspberry?

Comment: @dk1990 Your original question is easily answered BUT, connecting this to your RaPi is a lot more complex.

Comment: The Description sounded very easy. "Follow the traces connected to the button,  there should be 2 connections to each button.  One side of the button will be connected to a chip on the board (it will either be a black rectangle with legs, or a black plastic blob), the other end will be connected through a resistor  to either the battery + or the battery -."

Comment: @dk1990 It would help if you added a link to the tutorial.

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-home-automation/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: Above. I can't add it to the orig post because of the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. A typical keyboard matrix. Scanning the keyboard is done by pulling each row low in sequence and reading which, if any, column is pulled low by a switch. This arrangement allows a matrix of R x C buttons with only R + C pins on the chip.*

There is no link to the Instructable in your question but it sounds as though it is assuming that the remote input pin can simply be connected to circuit ground to simulate a button press. This is most likely not the case.

You could use a relay but a simpler all-electronic solution would be to use a CMOS switch such as a CD4016.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvSF7I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Shorting out the remote button using 1/4 of a CD4016 quad analog switch controlled by the Raspberry Pi.*

Comment: I put the instructable link in the description. This was marked as a beginners project but this sounds way more complicated. I'm a programmer so this isn't really my strong suit. He made a board between the remote and the raspberry pi. The CD4016 looks a bit like that board.

Comment: The Instructables site is too hard to read, multiple pages, popups, sign-ins. Sorry.

Comment: This would only be a beginners project if the assumption the author made were true, but it does not seem to be in your case.